# jQuery Tablesorter Column Selector Widget initially hide column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

The example page of this widget mentions a class "columnSelector-false" that should initially hide the column where it is added to the <th> tag.
[tablesorter column selector example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html)
But even on the example page it doesn't work:

```
<!-- columnSelector-false will initially hide the column -->
<th  class="columnSelector-false" data-priority="6" data-selector-name="Gender">Sex</th>
```

When you load the page, the Popup selector is set to "Auto", but even when I remove "Auto" the "Gender" column still shows.
Perhaps I missunderstand the meaning of "initially hide the column", but in that case I wonder what other meaning it has...

Hint:  The column selector widget does not work with colspan but you can use the <caption> tag instead if it is inserted before the <thead>.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using "columnSelector-false" does work. It doesn't appear to work if you change the column selector checkboxes in that demo because it saves your choices.

I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/115/) which includes a button to clear the saved columnSelector data, to show this behavior.

```
$('button.columnSelectorButton').click(function(){
    $.tablesorter.storage( $table, 'tablesorter-columnSelector', [] );
    $.tablesorter.storage( $table, 'tablesorter-columnSelector-auto', {} );
    // reload the page (for this demo only!)
    document.location.reload(true);
});
```

You can do the same thing by opening the browser development tools and clearing the local storage (press delete after clicking on the entry)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) from the plugin page

> Remove column from selection popup by including
>         **data-priority="Anything other than 1-6"** OR **data-column-selector="disable"** OR  **class="columnSelector-disable"**

```
<th  class="columnSelector-disable" data-selector-name="Gender">Sex</th>
```

This will hide the column from the selection popup.