# Tablesorter : columnSelector default hidden WITH columnSelector_saveColumns:true

Tags: hide, tablesorter

I have the same problem as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498818/jquery-tablesorter-column-selector-widget-initially-hide-column). My table shows several information such as the sector of a company. A sector can be classified in 4 levels so depending on the user he might want a general sector or a very detail one (to compare companies with help of a dropdown filter).

As said by Mottie in the post mentioned above, using "columnSelector-false" does work but as long as I don't set columnSelector_saveColumns to true. But I want both... There is about 16 columns and so, the user might be interested by some columns and wants to hide some without unchecking them every time he comes back to this page within the same session.

If nothing is stored, the default value (3 columns hidden on my case) should be applied. Then the values is stored in memory (hidden) and this value is used until the user select the column via the columnSelector and then the visible value is stored in memory etc...
Isn't is possible to do like that with the plugin?

Is there something I can do ?

Thanks for your help.

I'm using tablesorter v2.28.8.

**EDIT**
After several test, I've decided to reinclude the Auto mode (which I had deactivated). Indeed it did exactly what I want. So it becomes : 
`columnSelector_mediaquery : true // Auto mode activated
columnSelector_mediaqueryHidden: true // Hide columns defined as columnSelector-false so I can decide what to hide by default`.

But, I have a table with 16 columns (short width) : 3 are hidden by default, 5 are under a colspan. 
[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/zcxokzhL/4/) (without colspan) : It works as I want (columns are saved while not in auto mode, and in auto mode I decide which columns to show to the user)...but no colspan.

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/zcxokzhL/5/) (with colspan) : Once I have colspan the headers Type2 et Type 3 are not hidden in auto but 2 `<td>` have been hidden.

It's a bug, isn't ? 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There have been a bunch of changes to the columnSelector widget since v2.28.8; nothing related to the storage though. It would help me find a solution if you could provide a demo or share the HTML and JS being used.

Comment: Hi Mottie, Indeed the latest version is 2.29.0 I didn't know so much things has changed from 2.28.8. I made several test, reinclude the auto option etc.. See my edited post above with 2 demo

Comment: Hmm, well it looks like there is a bug when the columnSelector tries to process the rowspans. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1467), please use it to track the progress on the fix.

Comment: Thanks Mottie, really appreciate your work !